# Instrument-maintenance tag should be removed/aliased

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have instrument-maintenance and maintenance tags, seemingly serving the same purpose. The latter has the vast majority of usage.

I believe the former should be removed, or linked to the latter. But I can't see a direct way to do/propose this.

Is meta the right way to bring up such issues?

Comment: Yeah, meta's the right place, there's a proper synonyms 'system', but it doesn't really work on the smaller stack exchanges. (Or on Stack Overflow, for that matter of fact.) This one has already been brought up before, just needs a mod to make it happen. http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/a/1014/10938

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta is the right place, yes. Although chat is another option for relatively simple tings like tag synonyms. Your rep level should let you propose tag synonyms, just click on the tag, then the synonyms link near the top.

[image]

I have approved [instrument-maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-maintenance) as a synonym of [maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) so a search will bring up all tagged as either.

I notice a proposed further synonym of [instrument-care](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instrument-care), and the 9 questions currently under it all fit under [maintenance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) so I'll approve it too.

Comment: The second synonym isn't so clean-cut, although I guess it looks like there was a majority vote. http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/813/10938

Comment: Chris - thanks for making the original proposed synonym. Apologies for not following up until now. And at this stage I don't think there is any need to merge, so the tags all remain.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't so clear what I meant by my previous comment! I personally don't agree [tag:instrument-care] and [tag:maintenance] are synonyms...but it looks like there were more people on that question who thought they WERE synonyms, so on community-consensus, I guess they're fine to be synonymised. =)

Comment: @Chris Personally I don't think they're synonyms, but related closely enough that it would be useful to group them together.